# R: Extracting values from a dataframe when sequential row values differ

Tags: r

I have a data.frame `df` with 2 columns:

- `A` contains positive values.
- `B` contains values (either zero or a positive values).

I wish to generate a new data.frame (or vector) (of unknown length) containing
the values from `df[i+1, A]`, ONLY when `df[i, B] == 0 & df[i + 1, B] != 0`.

I can visualize how to do this by sequentially stepping through the data.frame using a loop, but this will take forever with >200,000 rows. What is the vectorized solution to a problem like this that requires arithmetic on sequential rows of a vector or data.frame?

Data is in this form:

```
      A    B
1     5    5
2    10    3
3    15    0
4    20    6
5    25    5
6    30    0
7    35    0
8    40   11
9    45    3
etc etc  etc
```

I'd then like to extract the values of `A` from row 4 (`A = 20`) and row 8 (`A = 40`) etc.

Comment: And what about the last row? Do we check only `df[i, "B"] == 0` then?

Comment: Stop at the last but one row would be how I'd program it as a loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
df$A[-1][diff(df$B != 0) > 0]
[1] 20 40
```

The idea is as follows. First, given a vector `c(1, 2)`, one way to extract `2` is of course `c(1, 2)[2]`. Another way is `c(1, 2)[c(FALSE, TRUE)]`, i.e. you might subset a vector by using a logical vector.

After you edited your question, I see that we are no longer interested in the first row of `df`, so that is why I start with `df$A[-1]`. Then one way that is longer and very likely less efficient, but follows more readable logic, is

```
df$A[-1][df$B[-nrow(df)] == 0 & df$B[-1] != 0]
```

where `df$B[-1] != 0` returns a logical vector corresponding to your condition `df [ i+1, B ] != 0`. Then `df$B[-nrow(df)] == 0` returns another logical vector corresponding to `df [ i, B ]==0`. Then operator `&` performs element-wise AND operation, returns the final logical vector and gives the result.

Now `diff(df$B != 0) > 0` is just a trickier way to write the same thing. `df$B != 0` gives a logical vector. Then while performing `diff(df$B != 0)` we are taking differences of 1's (correspond to entries `TRUE`) and 0's (correspond to `FALSE`). For example, `c(0, 1) != 0` gives `c(FALSE, TRUE)`, which can be seen as `c(0, 1)`, and then `diff` gives `1`. So, we have ones in `diff(df$B != 0)` where entry 0 is followed by some nonzero (in your case - positive) number. To use these results for subsetting `df$A[-1]` we obtain the final logical vector with `diff(df$B != 0) > 0`.

Comment: Thanks! Since I am a novice R user, would you care to explain the logic/structure/syntax of this answer?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description Julius. I am readign and re-reading to try to understand. Ithink one area I may be confused is that you mention subsetting - something I do frequently - but I do so using the subset function. i.e.
    a=subset(df, B == 0) etc
Are you saying this is the same as: a=df[B == 0] ?
And perhaps also the same as: a=(df$B ==0) ?
I am trying to learn as much as I can here...very slow going!

Comment: @Matt, it is always best to learn by practicing: take your `df` and check what these lines give you. You are close, `subset(df, B == 0)` gives the same as `df[df$B == 0, ]` (instead of `df[B == 0]`); intuitive syntax is `df[constraints for rows, constraints for columns]`, so I give no constraints for columns and give constraints for rows by a logical vector `df$B == 0` (you have to use `df$B` instead of `B`, because by writing `B` you just look for some other variable named `B` in your workspace). `df$B ==0` is something different: `df$B` is a vector and so `df$B ==0` is just a logical vector.

Comment: Thanks Julius, I am working through your examples now. QUESTION: Your solution doesn't strike me as all that obvious (at least to a novice). Is this a "clever" solution, or the only real way of performing vectorised math within/between elements of a vector?

Comment: @Matt, for sure that is not the only one solution. The ''standard'' one would be `df$A[-1][df$B[-nrow(df)] == 0 & df$B[-1] != 0]`. Mine is probably more efficient and shorter, you may call it clever. Most of the time there are multiple possible solutions.

Comment: Hi Julius. I can see that I need to rethink how to work with vectors. I now read/interpret your solution as: Take the subset of df$A (shifted up one row) where the values in df$B (excluding the last value)=zero AND where the values in df$B (shifted up one row) !=zero. That actually makes a huge amount of sense now, and I think will serve me well as my coding develops. I can think of lots of useful ways to use such syntax (summing sequential pairs of numbers for example). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option comes through 'dplyr' with the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(B != 0 & lag(B, 1) == 0)
```

This uses the dataframe and leaves rows where B doesn't equal 0 and the prior B does equal zero. This does return columns A and B. If you want to see only certain columns add `%>% select(...)` with the argument being variables separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

My example (adds together sequential values from two vectors):

```
> i1=c(1:100)
> i2=c(100:1)
> i3=i1[-length(i1)]+i2[-1]
> i3
 [1] 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
[55] 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

My example (adds together sequential values from a single vector):

```
> i1=c(1:100)
> i2=i1[-length(i1)]+i1[-1]
> i2
 [1]   3   5   7   9  11  13  15  17  19  21  23  25  27  29  31  33  35  37  39  41  43  45  47  49  51  53  55  57  59  61  63  65  67  69  71  73  75  77  79  81  83  85  87  89  91  93  95  97  99 101 103 105 107 109
[55] 111 113 115 117 119 121 123 125 127 129 131 133 135 137 139 141 143 145 147 149 151 153 155 157 159 161 163 165 167 169 171 173 175 177 179 181 183 185 187 189 191 193 195 197 199
```